# Mocking methods from a parent Class

Tags: spring-mvc, mocking, mockito, junit4, spring-test

I have a couple of classes as follows:

```
public class ControllerA {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    protected void methodControllerA() {
       userService.findAll();
       .... 
    }   
}

public class ControllerB extends ControllerA {

    @Autowired
    private AccountService accountService;

    public void methodControllerB() {
        accountService.findAll();
        methodControllerA();    
    }       
}
```

and I want to test the behaviour of **ControllerB.methodControllerB()**, so I 've created Junit class as follows:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {
    "classpath:services/testServiceContext.xml",
    "classpath:apply/applyController.xml",
    "classpath:testApplicationContext.xml",
    "classpath:testDatabaseMessageSource.xml",
    "classpath:controller/propertyeditors/propertyeditorsContext.xml"})
public class ControllerBTest {

    @Mock
    private AccountService accountService;

    @InjectMocks
    private ControllerB  controller;

    @Test
    public void methodControllerBTest() throws Exception {      

        controller = new ControllerB() {
            protected void methodControllerA() {                
            }
        };          
        controller.methodControllerB();
        asserts(); 
    }    

}
```

Of course when I instantiate the ControllerB() , accountService is not mocked, so I get a nullpointer when accountService is called, but if I don't instantiate ControllerB() I can't overwrite methodControllerA(), so I get a nullpointer in the Userservice inside this method...
Any ideas ? Thanks

Comment: How do you instantiate accountService/UserService? Are there any setters or contructors?

Comment: I forgot the @Autowired in the code. Edited

Comment: Where are you creating spring ApplicationContext that will inject those two classes in you test?

Comment: through @ContextConfiguration, I've just updated the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved !

```
AccountServiceImp accountService = mock(AccountServiceImp.class);
controller = new ControllerB() {
            protected void methodControllerA() {                
            }
};          
controller.setAccountService(accountService);
controller.methodControllerB();
```